# Chromecast / Cubetek Ezcast with Linux computer?

Tags: compatibility, screencasting, chromecast

I was pondering getting a [Google Chromecast](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/devices/chromecast/) or [Cubetek Ezcast](http://www.cubetek.com.sg/cubetek-air-streamer.html) the other day, mostly for its novelty and maybe using it as a media player or device to conduct presentations.

The way they set up, with the whole [DIAL](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/) technology seems a little weird to me, but that may or may not be due to the reason I've never seen it in action. I know however, that there are issues with some routers. This is a concern, as I have [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) routers, only.

I know the control app runs on Android, but what about my Linux laptop and/or desktop/workstation? I know Chrome uses a Chrome app, but is it gonna work if the client doesn't have a WLAN radio, but is otherwise connected to a wireless network access point (bridging both networks, mind you)? And what about OpenWrt, is it gonna work out of the box?

---

Now, there are at least two ways how I'd like to use the stick:

- As media player - pretty much in stand-alone mode, either playing streams off the internet
- As presentation dongle - so I can "take control" of any TV or projector featuring an HDMI port and use that for conducting a presentation or show a video, etc.

Are my use cases even covered by that? The idea is not to attach it permanently to my home TV, but instead have it with me on the go. The form factor almost implies mobility, even though attaching power to it seems a bit weird.

Both use cases should be covered by using my (Android) tablet, and Linux laptop.

---

In case I'm investigating the totally wrong cave, please suggest alternatives.

Comment: For Chromecast, if you (the client) and the Chromecast are on the same local network (connected to the same router), then it should work. I can use my Chromecast from Ubuntu through a DD-WRT router. Note that the Chromecast only supports sharing tabs in Chrome (in the case of desktops) and Chromecast-enabled apps and possibly some HTML5 videos (in the case of Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Cubetek Ezcast is like the Tronsmart EZcast, it probably has its own proprietary extension to uPnP protocol, which makes it near-unusable with anything but the EZcast software. I started digging into how to use it with Linux, but it [didn't seem possible at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423249/usage-of-coherence-or-gupnp-to-stream-a-v).

It's probably just a matter of time before someone reimplements the EZcast protocol, though.

Comment: It seems for my use case, this isn't what I need. Thanks for the input though.